# Why are there so many inexplicable tables under my crashlytics instance?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-analytics, crashlytics

I was experiencing the sandbox function of bigquery and encountered two problems:

1. Automatically import the data from **Crashlytics** into bigquery, but I don't know why, there are many inexplicable tables under the crashlytics instance. Should not have only appid_ Android and appid_ IOS two tables?
2. Automatically import the data from **Analytics** into bigquery. I don't know why I only imported the data of 11-08 and 11-11, but the other data of 11-09, 11-10 and 11-12 were not automatically imported, and I couldn't find Google's technical support...

Comment: could you please give some examples of tables name you can't identify on the dataset ? You should receive one table for each app as described in [this doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/bigquery-export#what-data-exported). Don't you have other apps inside the project ?

Comment: My app id is com.demo.app. In the firebase_crashlytics dataset, have more than 100 tabels, like com.demo.acr_ANDROID、com.demo.act_ANDROID、com.demo.acv_ANDROID and so on. And in my firebase account, I have only one Android project: com.demo.app. I don't know why the bigquery automatically creates so many tabels. @ewertonvsilva

Comment: You have created this app or imported from some example, or from the projects on the initial screen on the firebase ? Try creating it from scratch and using a different name of 'com.demo.app'. I believe you are receiving data from other project sourcers that are not yours.